# expired keys in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to create some pattern for key-value store, with structure like:

```
function ItemObject(value1, value2, value3) {
    this.value1 = value1;
    this.value2 = value2;
    this.value3 = value3;
    // or whatever object needs.
}
```

then, I make a function like:

```
function keystore() {
    this.keys = new Array();
    this.decaytime = 50000; //in second
}

keystore.prototype.storeKey = function(key, itemObject) {
    this.keys[key] = itemObject;
    setTimeout(this.removeKey(key), this.decaytime);
}

keystore.prototype.removeKey = function(key) {
    console.log('removing ' + key);
    console.log(this.keys);
    if (this.keys[key]) {
        delete this.keys[key]
    }
    console.log('done');
    console.log(this.keys);
}


module.exports = keystore;
```

Now, I want to make that `this.keys[keyid]` removed after `decaytime`. How can I do that? Because `this.removeKey()` is outside `setTimeout()` scope, and obviously, not a function since it is not declared yet in `setTimeout`. I need `removeKey()` as part of object because I want to remove key prematurely if needed, so I would keep `removeKey()`

Thank you

EDIT: I found a way, but it is ugly.

```
keystore.prototype.storeKey = function(key, itemObject) {
    this.keys[key] = itemObject);
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {_this.removeKey(key);}, this.decaytime);
}
```

Is there any proper way?

Comment: I think your best solution here will depend on your usage. There are many pros and cons to consider depending in how you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions for setTimeout, your `this` context will be maintained.

```
function keystore() {
    this.keys = new Array();
    this.decaytime = 2000; //in second
}

keystore.prototype.storeKey = function(key, itemObject) {
    this.keys.push(key, itemObject);
    setTimeout(() => this.removeKey(key), this.decaytime);
}

keystore.prototype.removeKey = function(key) {
    console.log('removing ' + key);
    console.log(this.keys);
    if (this.keys[key] != null) {
        this.keys = this.keys.filter((item, index) => index !== key);
    }
    console.log('done');
    console.log(this.keys);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively,  `setTimeout(function() {this.removeKey(key);}.bind(this), this.decaytime);`

Comment: Thank you.. I am using `() =>` form.